# Is it possible to create a folder in parent publication but hidden to child publication

Tags: blueprint

While going through the CME documentation I stumbled following text about search folder:

"Localizing or unlocalizing a Search Folder:-
If a Search Folder is shared to a BluePrint Child Publication, you can localize the Search Folder to create a local copy. When you localize a Search Folder, you can edit the name and metadata. You cannot edit the type or search criteria. You can also unlocalize a Search Folder to use the shared Search Folder from a Parent Publication."

Going through the first line 'If a Search Folder is shared to a BluePrint Child Publication,...' it seems it is possible to create a folder in parent publication which would not be visible to child publication. Is this possible to create such component/folder/SG etc.

Answer (score 3):

If a given publication is set to inherit from another publication (as a child), then everything from the parent is shared by default. You may then change the properties of the inherited items by localizing them.

So it is possible to do this by localizing the Folder in the child Publication and removing all the Permissions for the given user's group.

You will also need to go into the CM Snap-in on the CM server and under General set it to "Hide organizational items if no access to content"=true.

Comment: I am not sure you even need to localize the folder, if you set permissions on it accordingly in the parent, but then I am not sure why you would want to do this...

Comment: That's true, but then you won't see it in the parent either. My takeaway from the question's title was that it needed to be shown in the parent, but hidden in the child (assuming we're talking about the same user group).